# How come I need to close the db after I set this.getReadableDatabase()?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having the same issue as the user in the link below. He mentioned that an empty database gets created only on a particular android device(for me, it's the pixel, for him, a different android phone). However, on most of the android phones, the behavior currently in the code works.

There's a solution posted where someone mentions to add `db.close()` after `this.getReadableDatabase()` to fix the issue. However, I'm not sure why that fixed it and why does the behavior only work on certain android devices?

Here's the link: 
http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html

Comment: The real issue is opening the database as part of the copy process. This is done to create the databases directory. A better way is to check the database to see if it exists as a file. If it doesn't then check to see if the parent directory exists and create it if it doesn't exist. Then copy the database file(s) and then open the database. [The answer here, explains in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008907/ship-android-app-with-pre-populated-database/56012043#56012043)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you don't need to IF you use the correct technique BUT if you use the historically frequently used method, as below, then you have to because :-

The reason that `this.getReadableDatabase()` is/has been used is to create the databases folder/directory in the data/data/the_package/ directory. If the database directory doesn't exist then the typical copy from the assets fails with a ENOENT error.

With SQLite using journal mode logging by default this is no issue, hence why historically the *get-around* of using `this.getReadableDatabase()` has worked.

However, with Android Pie (28), the SDK has been changed to use Write-Ahead logging (WAL) by default, which is a later and more advanced logging method. This method uses two files that have improved safety measures. One being that the files are tagged/marked as belonging to the database that created them.

So when the database is copied using the old method without the close the two files (the database file suffixed with -wal and -shm) exist and will very likely contain logging data (such as the creation of any tables). However, they will not be tagged as being for the copied database, so (I believe) the database is recreated (as the copied database cannot be opened because of the mismatch between the database and the -shm and -wal files) and hence the ensuing **table not found** error that is typically encountered.

With WAL closing the database/connection results in the data being committed and hence why close the database after (immediately) the `this.getReadableDatabase()` works.

However, the correct fix is to check for and create the databases directory if it doesn't exist, using the File methods. There is then no need to open the database, which is wasteful of resources, and also no need to close the database, which is also wasteful of resources (i.e. the logged actions are actually undertaken and the data written to disk and the -wal and -shm files are also read and re-written).

Comment: Thanks for the write up! Just kind of weird with new devices running newer apis like samsung s9, this doesn't occur, only on the pixel however.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is due to the fact that every Android release brings a different SQLite version and some vendor customize SQLite library version too. As you can read from [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html):

```
Android API SQLite Version
API 27  3.19
API 26  3.18
API 24  3.9
API 21  3.8
API 11  3.7
API 8   3.6
API 3   3.5
API 1   3.4
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not the reason/problem (although close for 28+ when the issue many face is a change not to SQLite but to the SDK which opens SQLite in WAL mode by default). The real issue is laziness as such, copying code that uses open to create the databases directory. If the directory is created, when needed, using File methods (mkdirs), the waste of opening a db to just overwrite it and the ensuing issues are not introduced. [This explains in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008907/ship-android-app-with-pre-populated-database/56012043#56012043)