# Sqlite DB not working at android pie: no such tables found

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class DBManager {


public static final String DATABASE_TABLE= "registration";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userinfo.sqlite";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
final Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;


public DBManager(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(newVersion>oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}

// ---opens the database---
public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}



//Copies database from internal memory to the activity/fragement, To use the internal db
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();

    if (mDataBaseExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist

    } else {

        DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/** This method checks whether database  exists or not **/
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath()
                .toString();

        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


//  Creates and copies database from assets folder to internal memory,
//  must be run at least once when app is installed

public long copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    String DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath()
            .toString();

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    return length;
}
```

Error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: registration (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from registration where username = ? and password = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with android 9 there are two additional files that are part of the SQLite database, and if you copy a database overlaying an existing database, and don't delete those two other files first, then the database will consider itself corrupted. See this answer: [Ship android app with pre populated database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008907/ship-android-app-with-pre-populated-database/56012043#56012043)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to `DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();` being used prior to the copy.

This is used (misused would be more apt) to create the **database** folder/directoyr in the data/data/the_package/  folder/directory.

- misuse as it's overkill just to create a directory.

What happens is that this opens the database and in the case of Android 9+ results in two additional files, the -wal and -shm files being created as Android 9+ defaults to using Write-Ahead Logging.

When the database file is copied over the newly created file the two other files remain. When the database is opened after the copy the two files do not match the copied database and the open fails but is captured resulting in a new database being created.

There are a few ways that this can be circumvented.

- The database could be opened by forcing the use of Journal mode e.g. overwriting the **onConfigure** method to call [enableWriteAheadLogging(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#enableWriteAheadLogging()).

  - NOT RECOMMENDED as the benefits of [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) are lost.
- Delete the **-wal** and **-shm** files before the copy.

  - NOT RECOMMENDED as the overheads of of the unnecessary open and the deletion of the files created are still present.
- Create the **databases** folder instead of calling `getReadableDatabase()`

  - although this is recommended as such. There are still unnecessary overheads with using  `checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);` to see if the database file exists.
- Check the existence of the database as a **File** and if it doesn't exist use the **File**'s **mkdirs** method to create the databases directory (of whatever directories would be required if this directory changed).

  - This is recommended way.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008907/ship-android-app-with-pre-populated-database/56012043#56012043) provides code (see the **checkDataBase** method) that does the latter, noting that you should additionally delete the line `DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue and solved this adding this to my SQLiteOpenHelper

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem